# XPath query not returning result as sequence of nodes in document order using VTDNav/AutoPilot

Tags: xslt, xpath, xml-parsing

I have the following xml structure.

```
<body>
    <level recover="true">1</level>
    <span>
        <level recover="true">1.1</level>
        <span>
            <level recover="true">1.1.1</level>
        <span>
    <span>
    <level recover="true">2</level>
    <level recover="true">3</level>
<body>
```

`xpath query: //*[@recover='true']"`

*result: 1, 2, 3, 1.1, 1.1.1*

Seems that xpath processor build the result depth by depth. First processes the first depth level, from where it retrives **1, 2, and 3**, then goes to the second depth level and retrieves **1.1** then to the third level and retrives **1.1.1**.

What I need is to retrive the result in the following order:
**1, 1.1, 1.1.1, 2, 3**

**UPDATE** 
As XML Processor I am using https://vtd-xml.sourceforge.io/userGuide/4.html

```
VTDGen vtdGen = new VTDGen();
vtdGen.setDoc(xmlByteContent);
VTDNav vtdNav = vtdGen.getNav();

AutoPilot autoPilot = new AutoPilot(vtdNav);
autoPilot.selectXPath("//*[@recover='true']");
```

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ximpleware</groupId>
    <artifactId>vtd-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting. In XPath 2.0 this expression is defined to return a sequence of nodes in document order, which is the order you are looking for. In XPath 1.0 the order isn't defined, but I thought that all commonly-used XPath 1.0 processors returned the result in document order, because that's what XSLT requires, and most XPath 1.0 processors are designed with XSLT in mind. It seems you've found an exception.

It would be interesting to know what XPath processor you are using. You may need to move to a different one.

The results you are getting are conformant with the XPath 1.0 specification, but still rather a surprise.

**LATER**

I don't know VTD except by reputation. From what I understand, they've engineered it with performance as the #1 objective to the exclusion of all else. So if the spec allows them to return nodes in any order, I'm not that surprised they would take advantage of that. You'll have to look in the VTD documentation to see if there's any way of forcing document order in the results. Or experiment: see what happens if you add `|//*[@recover='true']' to the expression (they might sort into document order to implement the union operation efficiently).

**FURTHER UPDATE**

The method `AutoPilot.iterate()` claims to return selected nodes in document order.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Michael. I enriched the question with other info if you want to have a look.